# how to get latest posts from 2 different WordPress sites in the same host?

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

i made a custom php file to get latest posts from 2 wordpress websites in the same host i use this code in 2 files

**example.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('../wordpress/wp-load.php');
?>
        <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class=col-sm-4>
<div class="feature feature-1">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target=_blank>
<img width="364" height="205" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>">
<div class="feature__body boxed boxed--lg ask boxed--border">
<h3><?php the_title();?></h3>

</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**example1.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('../wordpress1/wp-load.php');
?>
        <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class=col-sm-4>
<div class="feature feature-1">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target=_blank>
<img width="364" height="205" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>">
<div class="feature__body boxed boxed--lg ask boxed--border">
<h3><?php the_title();?></h3>

</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

*and use in front index.php*

```
<?php include 'example.php';?>
<?php include 'example1.php';?>
```

> file structure
>
> example.com/wordpress/wp-load.php example.com/wordpress1/wp-load.php
>
> example.com/mainWebSite/example.php example.com/mainWebSite/example1.php

works fine only the first one if i switch only **what come first will work**
and other file will get same result from first WordPress site
i want it to get latest posts from 2 different wordpress sites in the same host

Comment: `require_once('../wordpress1/wp-load.php');` should be `require_once('wordpress1/wp-load.php');` as per your directory structure...

Comment: sorry there is a folder for mainWebSite i correct it as i mention it's working and get latest post but only from the first file